# Unit testing a Func<Delegate> with Rhino Mocks throwing InvalidCastException with second Expect() invocation

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm unit testing a class that gets some parameters injected by Autofac.

Some of the parameters are `Func<Delegate>`.  This allows me to create multiple delegates to use.  Refer to [this Autofac Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes) if you need a better description.

Here's part of the class.

```
public class CreateProductCommand : TransactionalDBCommandBase<ProductImpl>
{
    public delegate CreateProductCommand Factory(ProductInfo info, IAppSecurityContext context);

    private ProductInfo _info;
    private Func<SaveTextMasterCommand.Factory> _saveTextMasterCommandFactory;
    private Func<SaveTextValueCommand.Factory> _saveTextValueCommandFactory;
    private SaveProductCommand.Factory _saveProductCommand;

    public CreateProductCommand(ProductInfo info, Func<SaveTextMasterCommand.Factory> saveTextMasterCommandFactory, 
        Func<SaveTextValueCommand.Factory> saveTextValueCommandFactory, SaveProductCommand.Factory saveProductCommand, IAppSecurityContext context)
    {
        this._info = info;
        this._saveTextMasterCommandFactory = saveTextMasterCommandFactory;
        this._saveTextValueCommandFactory = saveTextValueCommandFactory;
        this._saveProductCommand = saveProductCommand;
        this.CurrentContext = context;
    }

    public override ProductImpl Execute(IDataTransaction dataTrans)
    {
         //More code here
         this._saveTextMasterCommandFactory().Invoke(SomeParam,SomeParam2).Execute(dataTrans);

        //Some time later
        this._saveTextMasterCommandFactory().Invoke(SomeDiffParam,SomeDiffParam2).Execute(dataTrans);
    }
}
```

The test class looks like this. The SetUp is HUGE. I'll align the left side of the code block where the issue is.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class CreateProductCommandTests
    {
        private IDataTransaction _dtMock;
        private IDataAccessAdapter _daaMock;

        private Func<SaveTextMasterCommand.Factory> stmfMock;
        private Func<SaveTextValueCommand.Factory> stvfMock;
        private SaveProductCommand.Factory saveProductDelMock;
        private ProductInfo info;
        private IAppSecurityContext context;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            this._dtMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataTransaction>();
            this._daaMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataAccessAdapter>();
            this._dtMock.Expect(m => m.DataAccessAdapter).Repeat.Any().Return(this._daaMock);
            stvfMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Func<SaveTextValueCommand.Factory>>();
            stmfMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Func<SaveTextMasterCommand.Factory>>();
            context = new AppSecurityContext() { LanguageID = 1 };

            info = new ProductInfo()
            {
                CatalogNumber = "CatalogNumber",
                BrandID = 1,
                ProductDescription = "ProductDescription",
                ProductName = "ProductName"
            };

            //Mock the command
            var nameTextMaster = new TextMasterImpl() { AltTextMasterID = new Guid().ToString("N"), IsCoreAppText = false, TextMasterID = 1 };
            var nameTextMasterMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveTextMasterCommand>(null, null);
            nameTextMasterMock.Expect(m => m.Execute(Arg<IDataTransaction>.Is.Equal(this._dtMock))).Return(nameTextMaster);

            //Mock the Delegate that creates it.
            var nameTextMasterFactoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveTextMasterCommand.Factory>();
            nameTextMasterFactoryMock.Expect(m => m(Arg<TextMasterImpl>.Is.Anything, Arg<IAppSecurityContext>.Is.Anything)).Return(nameTextMasterMock);

//This call here is fine.  Passes with no problem.
            stmfMock.Expect(m => m()).Return(nameTextMasterFactoryMock);

            //NameTextValue Mocking.
            var nameTextValue = new TextValueImpl() { LanguageID = 1, ContentText = "NameTextValue", TextMasterID = 1, TranslationStatus = 0, TextValueID = 1 };
            var nameTextValueMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveTextValueCommand>(null, null);
            nameTextValueMock.Expect(m => m.Execute(Arg<IDataTransaction>.Is.Equal(this._dtMock))).Return(nameTextValue);

            var nameTextValueFactoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveTextValueCommand.Factory>();
            nameTextValueFactoryMock.Expect(m => m(Arg<TextValueImpl>.Matches(n => n.TextMasterID == nameTextMaster.TextMasterID && n.ContentText == info.ProductName),
                Arg<IAppSecurityContext>.Is.Anything)).Return(nameTextValueMock);

            stvfMock.Expect(m => m()).Repeat.Once().Return(nameTextValueFactoryMock);

            //DescriptionTextMaster Mocking
            var descTextMaster = new TextMasterImpl() { AltTextMasterID = new Guid().ToString("N"), IsCoreAppText = false, TextMasterID = 2 };
            var descTextMasterMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveTextMasterCommand>(null, null);
            descTextMasterMock.Expect(m => m.Execute(Arg<IDataTransaction>.Is.Equal(this._dtMock))).Return(descTextMaster);

            //Delegate mock
            var descTextMasterFactoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveTextMasterCommand.Factory>();
            descTextMasterFactoryMock.Expect(m => m(Arg<TextMasterImpl>.Is.Anything, Arg<IAppSecurityContext>.Is.Anything)).Return(descTextMasterMock);

//THIS call fails with an InvalidCastException
            stmfMock.Expect(m => m()).Return(descTextMasterFactoryMock);

            var descTextValue = new TextValueImpl() { LanguageID = 1, ContentText = "DescTextValue", TextValueID = 2, TextMasterID = 2, TranslationStatus = 0 };
            var descTextValueMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveTextValueCommand>(null, null);
            descTextValueMock.Expect(m => m.Execute(Arg<IDataTransaction>.Is.Equal(this._dtMock))).Return(descTextValue);

            var descTextValueFactoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveTextValueCommand.Factory>();
            descTextValueFactoryMock.Expect(m => m(Arg<TextValueImpl>.Matches(n => n.TextMasterID == descTextMaster.TextMasterID && n.ContentText == info.ProductDescription), 
                Arg<IAppSecurityContext>.Is.Anything)).Return(descTextValueMock);

            stvfMock.Expect(m => m()).Repeat.Once().Return(descTextValueFactoryMock);

            var product = new ProductImpl() { ProductNameTextID = nameTextMaster.TextMasterID, DescriptionTextID = descTextMaster.TextMasterID, CatalogNumber = info.CatalogNumber, ProductID = 1 };
            var saveProductCommandMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveProductCommand>(null, null);
            saveProductCommandMock.Expect(m => m.Execute(Arg<IDataTransaction>.Is.Equal(this._dtMock))).Return(product);

            saveProductDelMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SaveProductCommand.Factory>();
            saveProductDelMock.Expect(m => m(Arg<ProductImpl>.Is.Equal(product), Arg<IAppSecurityContext>.Is.Anything)).Return(saveProductCommandMock);
        }
}
```

Exception is: Unable to cast object of type 'ProxyDelegate_Factory_3Proxyef78e79dacee4c759351a5ffaa933f85' to type 'Factory'.

I'm not exactly sure how to get this fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggestion isn't particularly inspired by the exception message you receive, so it may not help.  It seems to me that you haven't given enough information to the mock repository, however:

```
stmfMock.Expect(m => m()).Return(nameTextMasterFactoryMock);
//...
stmfMock.Expect(m => m()).Return(descTextMasterFactoryMock);
```

You've got the same mock expecting the same method to be called (i.e., `Invoke`), and you're telling it to return two different things.  How about this:

```
stmfMock.Expect(m => m()).Repeat.Once().Return(nameTextMasterFactoryMock);
//...
stmfMock.Expect(m => m()).Repeat.Once().Return(descTextMasterFactoryMock);
```

Comment: Definitely missed this, but it still didn't get rid of the exception.

Comment: I've looked over your code a couple of times and I can't find any reason why the proxy wouldn't inherit from the correct `Factory` type.  I would try using a repository instance rather than the static `Generate...` methods; I generally find that approach to work more smoothly, but that could just be because I'm more familiar with that approach.

Comment: You actually lead me in the right direction. I rewrote it in a fashion to not cause two expects on that object and I was able to side step it.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidAndroidDev I'm happy I could help -- I had a feeling it would be something like that.