# Rhino mocks is unable to set an expectation on the 2nd call of mocked object whose interface returns a Func<T>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to set an expectation on a mocked interface which returns a func from one of its methods. Unfortunately it looks like rhino mocks chokes when casting the 2nd return type or at least that's what I get from the exception. The exception is thrown from the Expect call.

```
public interface IFuncTest
{
    Func<int> Generate(int num);
}

[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IFuncTest>();

    // first expectation will succeed
    myMock.Expect(mm => mm.Generate(42)).Return(() => 6)

    // second expectation will throw inside the lambda passed to Expect
    myMock.Expect(mm => mm.Generate(4000)).Return(() => 9)
}
```

The order of the expectations doesn't matter.

Exception text:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ProxyDelegate_Func`1_1Proxy5f00ec19448d4e4c96f5d6df12f2c87d' to type 'System.Func`1[System.Int32]'.
    at Castle.Proxies.IFuncTest`1Proxy2cc837d117f745dfb24033b9bf7cb0f4.IFuncTest`1.Generate(Int32 tee)
    at Tests.Tests.<MyTest>b__9(IFuncTest`1 mm) in Tests\Tests.cs:line 167
    at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Expect[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
    at Tests.Tests.MyTest() in Tests\Tests.cs:line 167
```

Any ideas for why this is the case or how to fix it?

Comment: It seems you have the same issues as described here: https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks/issues/6

Comment: Interesting, it seems this is still not working? I tried running the test in https://github.com/alaendle/rhino-mocks/commit/1300043a6711664b5027cac57914dad36d13fd72 and the test failed. I couldn't tell if Norbi found a solution from what he said.

Comment: Some more searching yielded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076819/unit-testing-a-funcdelegate-with-rhino-mocks-throwing-invalidcastexception-wit but no fix

Answer (score 1):

I submitted recently a similar bug with Action.

See:https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks/issues/21#event-707223576

It is already fixed. This fix also fixes this issue. If you get the source from github and build it works fine.